# Data file in Python module extracted to where?

Tags: python, manifest, package, pypi, devpi

I have a Python package like this (reduced):

```
├── data
│   └── folder
│       └── file.dat
├── MANIFEST.in
└── setup.py
```

My setup file includes:

```
include_package_data = True,
```

Have a Manifest like this:

```
include data/folder/file.dat
```

When I package the project, I have file.dat in there.

Then having package in package index and installing from there, succeeds but with no file.dat anywhere I can find.

I tried

```
eager_resources = ['data/folder/file.dat']
```

didn't work.

What do I really need to make sure file.dat is extracted? Where is it extracted when the package from package index is installed?

Comment: Assuming you installed the package with `pip`: `pip show -f pkgname` will list all installed files with paths relative to the location (printed after `Location:`.